# Static keys in Google Guava

Tags: enums, hashmap, guava, google-guava-cache

I want to declare a cache like this `LoadingCache<EnumKeys, Map<String,String>>` in `Guava`. Can we have `enum` as keys in guava? When we create `Map` for `enum` we use `EnumHasMap`. Does something similar exist for `Guava` too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Enum` is still an `Object`, so yes, you can definitely use them as keys for a `LoadingCache` (and they have the advantage of being immutable, which is essential for keys).

However, there's only one implementation of `LoadingCache`.